# Bandwidth: How many nodes can a 15Mbps connection serve?

Tags: bandwidth

I have looked for an answer but can't seem to find what I'm looking for so thought I'd ask here.

We have decided to get a connection from a local ISP offering an upload speed of 15Mbps to serve a site we've developed. We expect that the site will have a decent about of traffic after about 5 or 6 months. During the initial 6 months, I don't plan to have any more than maybe 100 to 200 people a day coming to the site.

The site is all image based, so a single pageload may be around 3Mb each.

I'm concerned that maybe 15Mbps may not be able to serve very many nodes simultaneously. Is there a formula to figure this out? Or maybe even a calculator that can address this question?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? you have totally not defined any numbers that we could type into a fomula outside the bandwidth. What about sitting down and doing some basie school math and then asking for a validation?

Comment: Such a web site would be slow with _one_ user. 200 is impossible. If this is meant to be a serious web site, host it in a proper facility with sufficient bandwidth.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

15 Mbps for 200 people? Assuming all those people will be accessing email and browsing the web at more or less the same time then no 15 Mbps will probably not be enough. I'd go for 50 Mbps if you don't expect much video streaming / remote connections to be done, but if people on your site like Youtube (which I do NOT recommend as you will NEVER hear the end of it.) or you have people working from home via VPN either block Youtube or get 75 - 100 Mbps. And if you have many remote users I would try and make it SDSL for the faster upload speeds.

Although you didn't give much information on what those 200 people will be *doing* on site so 100 Mbps could be overkill. I mean, if these people are just construction workers setting things up before the real users get there then they will probably not need even the 15. But if these people are all high workload office employees that are doing web conferencing and getting 25 emails a minute with big fat excel attachments and PDFs on each one while they watch Netflix and stream music and talk on their VoIP phones then the 100 Mbps would be a safer bet.

TLDR: It Depends. Give us more info

Edit: This Answer doesn't address the original question because I apparently suck at reading comprehension. Disregard.

Edit2: Let this edit serve as my actual answer:

"If the 200 people that are accessing your site aren't constantly reloading the webpage and are just using it "normally" than 15 Mbps should be adequate, at least for the 6 months. You might wish to upgrade to a package with higher upload speeds if/when the daily user count starts to rise."

Comment: Jason, thank you for your input. I was kind of afraid of that. I'm looking into a data center option (colo) but it's way too expensive at this point. If I can use this 15 Meg connection for a few months while the site builds traffic, then I can move it into a data center where the connection won't be an issue.  Regarding the connection speed, there is no 50 Mbps option at this point. The only packages they have are a 200/15 and a 300/20 connection. I don't think an additional 5 Megs will do much in the way of serving more people. The users will be uploading images and surfing images.

Comment: I don't think this comment answers the original question, which was how much bandwidth is necessary to serve content from a particular site. The question you answered seems to be: How much bandwidth would 100 users need for internet access?

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. All I would like to know is how many 4MB pages a 15 Mbps connection can serve before it maxes out.

Comment: 0.53125 pages/sec ... Assuming: No disk latency, no CPU latency and data transfer at line speed that you are guaranteed (i.e., 15 mb/s == 2.125 MB/s). Of course this is a total farce, since there is always overhead.

Comment: It seems I misinterpreted the original question. When I read "site" I took that to mean location, not as a website. In this case 15Mbps upload just so 200 people can load a single webpage is completely adequate assuming the webpages are a reasonable size. Sorry for the mix up, my bad.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you clarified that, I was just reaching for my Lithium. ;)  Yes, the website is what I was referring to. Each webpage is approximately 4MB each. Is your answer still accurate with these figures?

Comment: If the 200 people that are accessing your site aren't constantly reloading the webpage and are just using it "normally" than 15 Mbps should be adequate, at least for the 6 months. You might wish to upgrade to a package with higher upload speeds if/when the daily user count starts to rise.

Comment: Jason, this is very helpful, thank you. If you'd like to post this, I'll accept it.